# Time of minchah without an appropriate place

Tags: halacha, mincha-afternoon-prayer, tashlumin

Ploni is never in an appropriate place for davening during the afternoon. Either his boss does not appreciate him davening or he is in transit. For the purposes of this question, he is unable to get to anyplace where he can daven during the allotted time-frame.

Considering this, how should he daven minchah and when? Should he just daven tashlumin, or is there something else he should do?

Comment: You might want to specify the parameters of his inability to daven. If he is 100% unable to daven, then it's an ones and he obviously davens tashlumin. But I'm not convinced that being on transit makes one ineligible to daven, at least bediavad. Nor am I convinced that it's even permissible to hold such a job. Maybe he has to quit.

Comment: I don't really see where the question is here. If he is 100% unable to daven, then what are you asking? He can't daven.

Comment: Why can't he daven in transit?

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit of vagueness in your question. I assume that the worker gets a lunch break. I also assume that the break is either flexible, or if it must be taken at a fixed time, it's probably at the time of the earliest permissible time for mincha, even for b'di'eved. If so, that solves the time problem. As for "inappropriate place", if you can specify what makes it inappropriate, it would make it easier to answer. W/o this info, I'm assuming that there may be b'di'eved "options".

[Halchipedia](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Shemoneh_Esrei#Davening_sitting) mentions situations were one can daven shmoneh esreh while sitting. Offhand, I think that would solve the 2nd part of the question - "in transit". I am assuming this means "public transportation". If he is driving himself, that's probably a different story, as he may not have proper kavanah, though, it may be possible to drive and say Shmoneh Esreh - I'm unsure about that.

Lastly, if there is no other option, he is considered an "ones", and can daven tashlumim.

Please clarify some of the parameters in your questions, so that you get clearer answers.